# If i try to install pip install pan-aadhar-ocr

Tags: windows

Installing collected packages: regex, mpmath, urllib3, typing-extensions, sympy, six, PyYAML, Pillow, packaging, numpy, networkx, MarkupSafe, lazy_loader, idna, charset-normalizer, tifffile, scipy, requests, PyWavelets, python-bidi, pytesseract, opencv-python, jinja2, imageio, torch, scikit-image, torchvision, easyocr, pan-aadhar-ocr
DEPRECATION: regex is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
Running setup.py install for regex ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for regex did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [15 lines of output]
running install
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\regex
copying regex_3_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\regex
copying regex_3\regex.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\regex
copying regex_3_regex_core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\regex
copying regex_3\test_regex.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\regex
running build_ext
building 'regex._regex' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> regex

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Could you please help me out find out the solution